# Can the universe operate on a totally different set of laws?

Tags: universe, laws-of-physics

Recently, I learnt that there are many, many mathematically consistent set of universal laws.

How would a universe based on a totally different set of laws look like?

What are the mathematical conditions that make a set of laws consistent?

And lastly, why does our universe operates on the laws of physics known to us and not on any other set of laws?

Comment: I think this is too broad a question. You might read "Flatland" by Edwin A Abbott and consider how difficult eating is in the two dimensional universe even with the laws of physics as they are. There are many other publications and websites which discuss such ideas. http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~banchoff/Flatland/

Comment: You've heard wrong. No one knows even one complete set of laws. My personal opinion is that only one set is consistent, but this has not been proven yet.

Answer (score 1):

"How would a universe based on a totally different set of laws look like?"

Totally different.

"What are the mathematical conditions that make a set of laws consistent?"

The laws must not contradict each other.

"And lastly, why does our universe operates on the laws of physics known to us and not on any other set of laws?"

I'll get back to you on this, after we find out why anything at all exists.